# Timed Database Replication using Wamp Server mysql for Master- Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, wampserver, database-replication, master-slave

I am trying to replicate my database using master slave replication on my wamp server. I have made the following changes to my my.ini file:

```
# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel.The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

#Defining the directory for logs and database and the server id
log-bin=C:\wamp\logs\mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=bank
server-id=2
```

On Master Server I configured this:

```
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE 
-> ON *.* TO 'root'@'slave_ip' 
-> IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

On the slave server, I configured this:

```
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO 
-> MASTER_HOST='(master_ip)', 
-> MASTER_PORT=3306, 
-> MASTER_USER='root', 
-> MASTER_PASSWORD='';
```

I got the error: Error 1198: This operation cannot be performed with a running slave; run stop slave first.

So I ran stop slave and nothing happened. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

on master:

`SHOW MASTER STATUS;`

output is :

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      107 | karbord_test |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set
```

on slave:

```
STOP SLAVE;

CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=107;

START SLAVE;
```